# TrueCrypt External Multimedia Hard Drive

Tags: hardware, file-encryption

I have an external multimedia hard drive (1.36TB).  I made 4 partitions of 350GB each. Then I shredded the free disc space of all the partitions.

Now I want to put Truecrypt on the disk.   I can't put it on all 4 Partitions.  If I put it on all 4 Partitions, I can't use the hard drive for watching TV or films.
So I want to lock 3 partitions and leave one open.

I am worried that I won't get the full Truecrypt protection. Since one partition is open, you can just go to the computer, access the open partition, reformat the other three, then the password is gone and the you can run a file recovery program.

Comment: Formatting the encrypted ones does not help; that area remains encrypted and any data stored there cannot be recovered.

Answer (score 1):

With TryeCrypt, the files are encrypted on the hard disk, so if an attacker formats the partitions and he use a recovery software, the files will still be encrypted. By the way, even if all your parition would be encrypted, an attack could still format your hard drive.

The attacker needs the key to decrypt your files. The key is kept in the RAM of the computer who is decrypting the files. You must protect your computer from deep freeze attacks and of course you need to protect your computer from key logger that would steel your key when you type it. Also, you need to put a long key so a brute force attack will fail to decrypt your files.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the really quick Answer 

So if the Hard Drive is encryptet any Futer data that i put on there will be encryptet to right ? 

After i am finishd with my external i want to use DBAN  (Darik's Boot and Nuke) and clear out all the internal Hard Drives and encrypt them to 

Now to be sure that i dont get a keylogger witch anti vire Programm would you recommend i always used anti vire but i am not really sure that this is the best Programm

Comment: Yes, all files will be encrypted while you use the drive that is configured with TrueCrypt. To choose a good AV you can refer to this chart http://www.av-comparatives.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/avc_fdt_201303_en.pdf Also, Avast and Microsoft Security Essential are free and are fine. If you download an illegal anti-virus, you could get a virus from it.

Comment: Just one More thing if i encrypted a hard drive will the deleted Files that used to be on the drive also be encrypted ? Ore is it safer to shredder it before hand ?

Comment: Truecrypt is volume level encryption.  Anything within that truecrypt volume will be encrypted.  Any files, filesystem meta-data, deleted files.  Each and every block is encrypted.  The only way to access is it is by decrypting it.

Comment: @user24964 I am not sure on this one. It would depend of how TrueCrypt is made. To be sure, don't take any chance and wipe your disk carefully.

Comment: Ok Thanks right now i am using File Shredder v2.5 i think with 7 passes that schould do the deal i hope xD

Comment: So i am Back again with yet another Question 

The File Shredder just finishd 7pass wipe 
Just to be sure i let recuva run over it (just 1%) and i was surprised to find 175temp files and some other strange Files 

Does that mean the 7 wipe didn't work and the data is still recoverbal ??